# Printing Key codes

Tags: android, key

hi 
in android i want to print the key codes for each and every key which i pressed.
i am not getting any method from which i can print key codes.
plz help me because without getting keycode i m unable to complete my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override these methods in your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event);

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event);
```

Comment: Thanks.. it is working..but its not giving me home key and KEYCODE_ENDCALL key code. why?                   actually i want that if user press home key than an alert should be there not the home page? is this possible??

Comment: you cannot catch the home key. you can only define an activity as a default home intent, but not catch the keypress event in onKeyUp/Down. That's a restriction so that developers cannot keep users caught in their app.